# AJAX response is cached when using DOJO

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, dojo

I am using the below DOJO functionality for AJAX call. But unfortunately the respose for a particular request is cached. And even if I change the code in servlet side, its is not reflected for the cases where I have tried earlier. I guess the reponse is cached. I am using Tomcat server.
Can any one please help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMonth(text) { // 
  dojo.xhrGet({ 
    // The following URL must match that used to test the server.
    url: "ajaxServlet?s="+text, 
    handleAs: "text",
    // The LOAD function will be called on a successful response.
    load: function(response, ioArgs) { //
                    dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = response + "Hereeee"; // 
                    return response; // 
                },

    // The ERROR function will be called in an error case.
    error : function(response, ioArgs) { // 
                    console.error("HTTP status code: ", ioArgs.xhr.status); //
                    dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = 'Loading the ressource from the server did not work'; //  
                    return response; // 
                },

                // Here you put the parameters to the server side program 
                // We send two hard-coded parameters
                content : {
                    name : "lars",
                    url : "testing"
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a property that you can use that's called `preventCache` that will add a timestamp to each request (so cache is never used) if you set it on `true`, you can read more about it at the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/xhrGet.html#dojo-xhrget-supported-object-properties).

In your case it would be:

```
function showMonth(text) { // 
  dojo.xhrGet({ 
    // The following URL must match that used to test the server.
    url: "ajaxServlet?s="+text, 
    handleAs: "text",
    preventCache: true,
    // The LOAD function will be called on a successful response.
    load: function(response, ioArgs) { //
                    dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = response + "Hereeee"; // 
                    return response; // 
                },

    // The ERROR function will be called in an error case.
    error : function(response, ioArgs) { // 
                    console.error("HTTP status code: ", ioArgs.xhr.status); //
                    dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = 'Loading the ressource from the server did not work'; //  
                    return response; // 
                },

                // Here you put the parameters to the server side program 
                // We send two hard-coded parameters
                content : {
                    name : "lars",
                    url : "testing"
                }
            });
}
```

**Small note**: The caching isn't Dojo specific, it's because `GET` request should be used to request information, so that's why most browsers cache these requests to improve performance. All other type of requests (`POST`, `PUT`, ...) are usually not cached.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. That one worked. And thanks for the extra information.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. I used 'preventCache: true' inside the function.